# How microprossesor perfoms substration by 2's complement

Tags: theory, binary

How microprossesor perfoms substration by *2's complement* for 5 + (-3) ?
I know this might be basic, but to be honest I didn't get it at all.

```
5 = (0101) 

3 = (0011) ---> it's 2's complements  is 1100+1 which is 1101
```

now

```
     0101
     1101
     ______ +

     10010
```

why is the result `10010` ? it's not even *2* in decimal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ignore the carry at the end (4-bit operands with 4-bit accumulator) so you have

```
 0101 (5)
+1101 (-3)
-----
 0010 (2)
```